# Lookup last used primary key then adding one

Tags: vba, ms-access

This has probably been asked hundreds of times before, but I seem to be having trouble finding an existing question that addresses my situation.

My question in how can I access a primary key value located in the last record of a table? For example, if this is my table:

| WONumber | Account Name |
| --- | --- |
| WO1001 | Joe's Food Mart |
| WO1002 | Family Foods |
| WO1003 | Redneck Tabacca |

From a form, when I select "add record" I want to access the value "WO1003" (and then be able to add one to it). I found something close but it changes the last value, it doesn't use it in a new record. So, to be clear - using the above table, I want to create a new record from my form with the primary key value being "WO1004" but I'm struggling to figure out how to add the new primary key to the new record.

The code I found that's close is:

```
    Dim rs As Recordset
    'Query the last value, get the WONumber
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 WONumber FROM tblWorkOrders ORDER BY WONumber DESC")
    'Open it up for editing
    rs.Edit
    'Increment the number by 1
    rs.Fields("WONumber").Value = Left(rs.Fields("WONumber").Value, 2) & CInt(Mid(rs.Fields("WONumber").Value, 3, Len(rs.Fields("WONumber").Value) - 2)) + 1
    'Update the recordset
    rs.Update
```

Comment: To avoid such issues, the primary key should be a normal auto-number (1003, 1004 etc) and the `WO1004` should be constructed for presentation purposes only, e.g. `Select "WO"+[ID] AS Key`, assuming `[ID]` is the primary key.

Comment: The data in my table is imported from a mobile app where the Work Orders are auto generated. However, I sometimes need to manually generate work orders in Access and I want to keep the work order numbers sequential. My primary key is the work order number "WO1003" with well over 2 thousand records currently, so I don't want to have to rebuild my database/forms. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to replace the `WO` and convert the remaining chars to number, than to limit the number using the `Mid` function.

Keep in mind your solution will cause conflict errors on a multi-user environment.

```
Dim nextId As String
nextId = "WO" & CInt(Replace(Nz(DMax("WONumber", "tblWorkOrders"), "0"), "WO", vbNullString)) + 1

Debug.Print nextId

'WO1004
```

Steps:

1. Get the max value using the `DMax()` built-in function.
2. Provide a default value of "0" in case the table is empty using the `Nz()` function.
3. Remove the "WO" word, convert the remaining chars to an integer and increment by one.
4. Append back the word "WO".

---

You will then need to add the new record, not edit the last one.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblWorkOrders")

rs.AddNew
rs.Fields("WONumber").Value = nextId 
rs.Update
```

Comment: This worked 99% perfect. To get the new work order number to show up on the form, I just had to add me.requerry as the last line and now it's 100% working. Thanks Kostas K.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using your form's *Before Insert* event to compute the new `WONumber`.

My example form includes a text box named "txtWONumber" which displays the `WONumber` from the current record.

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngWO As Long
    Dim strSelect As String

    strSelect = "SELECT TOP 1 WONumber FROM tblWorkOrders ORDER BY WONumber DESC"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSelect, dbOpenSnapshot)
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        lngWO = CLng(Mid(rs!WONumber, 3)) + 1
        Me.txtWONumber = "WO" & Format(lngWO, "0000")
    Else
        Me.txtWONumber = "WO0001"
    End If
End Sub
```

With this approach, the new `WONumber` will be computed and displayed in the form's new record as soon as you input anything into any of the record's other fields.